# libcurl certificate caching policy

Tags: openssl, libcurl

Libcurl does not cache verifying certificates.
Investigating libcurl sources

```
cache_criteria_met = (data->set.general_ssl.ca_cache_timeout != 0) &&
           conn_config->verifypeer &&
           !conn_config->CApath &&
           !conn_config->ca_info_blob &&
           !ssl_config->primary.CRLfile &&
           !ssl_config->native_ca_store;
```

cache_criteria_met is false because conn_config->CApath is set to
/etc/ssl/certs.  All other variables are true. Why CApath is the problem for libcurl to cache? What can I do to enable caching?
Libcurl uses openssl 3.

OS: Linux Ubuntu

Compiler: gcc

Comment: libsurl does not have such code: https://github.com/curl/curl/search?q=cache_criteria_met Where have you got it from?

Comment: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/openssl.c

Comment: What cURL version do you use? You talked about Ubuntu, but it does not distribute the latest cURL version.